# Log likelihood is sufficient statistic

Tags: likelihood-ratio, sufficient-statistics

We have two hypotheses:

\begin{align}
\mathcal H_0&: X \sim P\\\mathcal H_1&: X \sim Q\end{align}

Define $F = \log \frac{dP}{dQ}$ to be used for the likelihood ratio test with threshold $\tau$. We want to show that $F$ is a sufficient statistic for testing $\mathcal H_0$ versus $\mathcal H_1$ but I'm not very well versed in this area and would like some intuition as to what's going on here. These notes say

> To show $F$ is a sufficient statistic, we need to show that $P_{X|F} =
> Q_{X|F}$.

How do I interpret this and why is it equivalent to $F$ being a sufficient statistic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A statistic $T$ is sufficient for some parameter $\theta$ if the distribution of the data $X$ conditional on $T$ does not depend on $\theta$.

Now, these conditional distributions for the two different parameter values under $H_0$ and $H_1$ appear to be denoted $P_{X|F}$ and $Q_{X|F}$ in your notation, so that sufficiency requires that these two distributions be the same, or $P_{X|F} = Q_{X|F}$.